# Not sure if I should use 'the' or 'a'

Tags: grammar, sentence

So I just commented (tried to, the answer turned out to have been deleted) on an answer and wrote this: "I also feel that the disclaimer was just a tincy wincy bit unnecessary". I then though to change it to this : "I also feel that the disclaimer was just a tinsy, wincy, littlest bit unnecessary".

I then thought that the 'a' should/could change to 'the' as in "I also feel that the disclaimer was just 'the' tinsy, wincy, littlest bit unnecessary". However I then realized I didn't actually really know which one it should be... In my mind at least, both seemed to be correct.

A slightly dumb and mundane question but still, it got my gears grinding a little bit so I thought to come here for some internet ultimate wisdom. Also in an afterthought: what's the correct use of commas within this quote?

Comment: I'm probably being too pedantic, considering the usual something of a mess I write. Perhaps nit picking is pointless :)

Comment: You're suffering from semantic satiation. So go with your original version, which was perfectly fine.

Comment: I kinda like the 'semantic satiation' it conveys a sort of playfulness I'm going for. Are you saying that the 'semantic satiation' illegitimises the sentence so therefor correct grammar doesn't really come into play?

Answer (score 1):

I think that it should be "the" instead of "a " because it says littlest not little.

Comma wise,there should only be 1. This comma is after tinsy wincey and before littlest- tinsy wincy is a phrase and therefore should stay together.It would be like saying something is on the small side;you wouldn't put a comma between the words.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, the article should match the first in the list of adjectives:

> The disclaimer was just a tinsy, wincy, littlest bit unnecessary.

But normally you would want them all to match, anyway:

> The disclaimer was just the tinsiest, winciest, littlest bit unnecessary.